# Unit and integration tests get the same names by default

Tags: unit-testing, grails, configuration

In Grails the unit tests and integration tests get generated with exactly the same naming convention, so that if you are testing a domain class named `Foo` both tests get generated with the name `FooTests`, in the same package. Is there an expectation I should have either a unit test or an integration test, but not both? Do people put their integration tests in a different package from their unit tests, or rename one? What's the preferred way to get around this?

btw I hacked on grails/scripts/_GrailsCreateArtifacts.groovy to change how the classes are generated in order to get it to generate different names (the value for the suffix property is all that changed). I don't like having to include something that means 'integration' in the name when the class is in a folder called 'integration', but this at least avoids having to do a manual rename.

```
createIntegrationTest = { Map args = [:] ->
    def superClass = args["superClass"] ?: "GroovyTestCase"
    createArtifact(name: args["name"], suffix: "${args['suffix']}IntTests", 
        type: "Tests", path: "test/integration", superClass: superClass)
}
```

Comment: What are you doing to generate the unit and integration tests?

Comment: @Jarred - I think he is using create-unit-test and create-integration-test commands, and yes, it would create the tests with same name in same package. I too does not know how people handle this, but I manually rename them

Comment: @Jarred: sudhir's guess is right, that's what I'm doing. I end up manually renaming the integration test to FooIntTests.

Comment: @NathanHughes - I think there's no configuration to change this behavior, you may be able to change the scaffolding templates to automatically put *IntegrationTests for create-integration-test command.

Comment: @sudhir: yes, i looked into that, I could do that. since the unit and integration tests use the same template it was easier to hack the createArtifacts script (which I would have to do in any case to use a different template).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think giving them a different name is the right choice.

```
*IntTests
```

or

```
*IntegrationTests
```